# light icons in darkmode

Tags: android, android-studio, android-vectordrawable

In Android Studio, I've added a bunch of icons to my app via <kbd>res</kbd> -> <kbd>New</kbd> -> <kbd>Vector Asset</kbd>. When I tested my app on a device with darkmode, I noticed, that some icons changed their color with the text color, while some remained black.

Upon further investigation I found the ones that changed their color had this attribute:

```
<vector
    android:tint="?attr/colorControlNormal"
```

while the ones that did not change their color had this one:

```
<vector
    android:tint="#000000"
```

The fix was easy: I just had to change the tint attribute accordingly.

My question is this: where is the tint attribute controlled in Android Studio? The dialog does have a color attribute, which is set to 000000. But I don't recall doing anything special before to end up with `tint="?attr/colorControlNormal"`.

How can I make Android Studio to always set tint to `?attr/colorControlNormal`?